# How to setup a master-detail page with Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having trouble setting up a "master-detail" view using Bootstrap 3. I'm attaching a picture of the specific layout I'm trying to get:
[image: Master-Detail layout]

I've created a div with `.row` spanning the 12 columns for the header, and then another `div.row` with a `div.col-md-4` and `div.col-md-8` for the two columns. But obviously this doesn't achieve what I'm looking for. I've tried playing with the position attribute, but it seems to conflict with the Bootstrap CSS and I always just get jumbled text.

Thank you very much in advance and let me know if you'd like me to provide more details on what I'm looking for. Hopefully the pic is clear.

Comment: "But obviously this doesn't achieve what I'm looking for" - why not? what is the problem?

Comment: Because it doesn't fix the header at the top, and it doesn't include a footer. I don't know how to add a new .row (the footer) so that it will always show at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Your issue is not solved with bootstrap - its vanilla CSS. To get fixed/floating elements you can use the position: fixed CSS attribute. Combine it wirh top:0px width:100% and height:100px you have a good place to start.

Comment: Sorry, can you give me a specific example? Also, I'd prefer to use (if possible) Bootstrap for the "responsive" features, like allowing different column widths depending on the device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for

```
position: fixed;
```

This ensures that the element is always static relative to the viewport. You will then use the relative positioning properties to place it where you want it to go.

For the top element (say, your navbar), you can set:

```
top: 0;
```

For the bottom element, you can set:

```
bottom: 0;
```

So, something like this:

```css
.row, .col-md-4, .col-md-8 {
    border: 2px solid pink; /* For showing the div borders */
}

.row.main-content {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 300px;
    margin-top: 20px; /* Needs to match the height of .row.top */
 }

 .row.top {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    height: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    z-index: 9999;
 }
    
 .row.bottom {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 20px;
   width: 100%;
    background-color: green;
    z-index: 9999;
 }

.scrollable {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 300px; /* May need to be set somehow */
  }
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid"><!-- To get it to take up the whole width -->
      
      <div class="row top">

      </div><!-- row -->

      <div class="row main-content">
        
        <div class="col-md-4">
        
            <div class="sub-header">
            </div>

            <div class="scrollable">
                <!-- menu items here -->
            </div>

            <div class="sub-footer">
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="col-md-8 scrollable">
            <!-- Product detail goes here -->
        </div>

      </div><!-- row -->

      <div class="row bottom">

      </div><!-- row bottom -->

    </div><!-- container-fluid -->
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried it on jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/3kow0qqo/) and it doesn't quite get the expected result. I fixed the typo on .row.main-content (setting height:300px), but it's still not working. Do you know what else would need to be changed?

Comment: Sure! For starters, I missed that the .row.main-content needs margin-top: (the height of the header), and that the .row.top (and possibly the .row.bottom, though that's a precaution rather than something which is necessary) both need a high z-index to keep them on top.

Comment: But I'll take a look and see if I can figure the rest out.

Comment: Try that now...  I added width: 100% to the main header and footer, as well as a border: 2px solid pink to each div and col-md-*. Anything else I missed?

Comment: Oh, and here's a fiddle with the changes. https://jsfiddle.net/L4ycoqtw/